Computer Misuse Act Section 1, Statute of Limitations
About 4/5 years ago, a girl I was friends with remained logged into an ex's Instagram account for about 6 months after their break up. She would regularly log in and read his messages, screenshotting them.
We're no longer friends as she was a terrible person, I'm talking 5 false rape allegations and 2 fake suicide attempts...
I've been planning to tell the guy she accused him of violently beating+raping her, which she also did. But now I'm wondering if I should also mention this to both him and the police....???
Thank you

Question seems to ask for advice for real circumstances, which is off-topic here.

Your post is unclear on this point, but if she has made a criminal complaint against this third party, and you have evidence that casts doubt on her likely testimony, then I should think that both the police and the defendant would want to know about it. There is AFAIK no legal duty on you to speak up, but I believe you have a moral duty to prevent a possible miscarriage of justice.

We can't advise you what you should do as legal advice is off-topic here.
However, addressing what appears to be the question in the title:
The offence under Section 1 of the Computer Misuse Act 1990 is an "either-way" offence. This means it can be tried either in a magistrates' court (summary offence) or in a crown court (indictable offence). As a general rule there is no limitation period for indictable offences or either-way offences tried as indictable offences. Legally, prosecution of such offences can be brought at any time. Practically, the CPS may decide that an old offence shouldn't be prosecuted due to lack of sufficient evidence related to the passage of time (e.g. fading memories, lost/destroyed documents, etc.).
